# Does the google+ iphone app url scheme (mgc://) support any parameters?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'd like to be able to launch the google+ iphone app and tell it to go into "compose" mode and supply it with some default text for the message. I can get it to launch using the mgc:// url scheme and have tried a bunch of url formats but can't get it to do anything but launch. Has anyone found anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old one! Priyanka - there is no way of going to the *app*, but there is a sharing lib for iOS that uses the browser, but gives you a good amount of control: developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share

Take a look:

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
  id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

  // This line will fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the item
  // you're sharing based on the URL you included.
  [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/"]];

  [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"I made reservations!"]

  [shareBuilder open];
}
```

You can also call out to open the Google+ app up, but you can't pass text to fill - you can do a URL though, by using gplus: in your UIApplication openURL call rather than http:. E.g. in Mobile Safari try:

```
gplus://plus.google.com/share?url=http://developers.google.com/plus
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Google Plus app to a specific page using a url in the following format:

```
gplus://plus.google.com/app/basic/+YourPageName/posts?source=appredir
```

You can figure out the redirect url for a specific page by setting the user agent in Safari on your Mac (via the Develop menu) to one of the `Safari iOS` variants, and then visiting a Google Plus page. The page will open, but the finder will also give an error because the page tried to open a `gplus://` url it didn't know what to do with. It'll show you the url that gave the error.

Using that url in a `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]` call will open the Google+ app. Don't forget to wrap it in a `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]` call in case the user doesn't have the Google+ app.